# Input Values Only Return Undefined in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I am pretty new to react native and am trying to get the home page of my first basic app to load. Currently, it asks users to input their "name" and "networth" and I simply want to return the networth input multiplied by a constant with an alert that appears after pressing submit saying "{name} + " net worth will be " + {newNetworth} + " next year!". However right now my output is: "undefined will be worth undefined next year!" and I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get the actual values to pass through.

Here is my child component:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class OpeningPageQs extends React.Component {
  
    
    state = {
    name: '',
    networth: 0,
    newNetworth: 0
}

nextYearWorth() { 
    

    this.setState({
        name: this.state.name,
        newNetworth: this.state.networth * 1.1
    });
return (alert(this.name + ' will be worth ' + this.newNetworth + ' next year!'));

}


    render (){
        

        return (
        <View>
            <TextInput style= { styles.input }
                placeholder= "name"
                onChangeText= { this.name }
            />

            <TextInput style= { styles.input }
                placeholder= 'networth'
                onChangeText= { this.networth }
            />

            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.submitButton}
            onPress = {
                () =>  this.nextYearWorth(this.state.name, this.state.networth)
            }
            >
             
                <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>
                Submit
                </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity> 
        </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingTop: 23
    },

    input: {
        margin: 15,
        height: 40,
        borderColor: '#7a42f4',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    submitButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
        padding: 10,
        margin: 15,
        height: 40,
     },
     submitButtonText: {
         color: 'white'
     }
})


export default OpeningPageQs;
```

And here is my Parent component:

```
 import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import OpeningPageQs from './components/OpeningPageQs';

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor (props){
        super(props);
    
    //building initial state for input props
        this.state = {
        
          name: '',
          networth: this.networth 
        
    
        };   
    
      }
    
    
      render(){
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
          <OpeningPageQs 
          name={this.state.name}
          networth={this.state.networth}
           />
        </View>
      );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Reffering to: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

You are wrongly setting the state. Try like this:

> ```
>         <TextInput style= { styles.input }
>            placeholder= "name"
>            onChangeText={text => this.setState({name: text})}
>         />
> ```

It may be worth not setting the state just to show the results. You can either create local variable in nextYearWorth method, or multiple the value when setting the state inside onChangeText callback.

For the alert - please take a look at Modal component: https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#docsNav

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The main reason I would like to set state here is so that I can eventually add "savings" and "ideal growth rate" as input variables and work them into the nextYearWorth method. I tried implementing the changes as applicable to each TextInput but am still getting the same output. I might just need to do more reading up on state and get a more holistic understanding of the processes it uses

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that.

```
<TextInput style= { styles.input }
    placeholder= "name"
    onChangeText= { text => this.name = text }
/>
```